# What does the phrase "A falling knife has no handle" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I saw this commented on reddit, and I can't understand the phrase.  Is it metaphorical or literal?

Answer (score 3):

It means: do not try to catch a falling knife, you will cut yourself.
In a reflex, [people actually try this](https://www.kitchenknifeforums.com/threads/a-falling-knife-has-no-handle.17543/).

And yes, it is also used metaphorically, e.g. in finance/investing relating to falling stocks.

[Related question on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59591/origin-of-the-expression-trying-to-catch-a-falling-knife)